# online installer Qt for chessx on Centos 6.4 compile with qmake

Tags: software-installation, qt4

Using `yum install qt` has installed  `qt.i686 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5` to my `/usr/share` folder on Centos 6.5 but I need to follow these instructions to get chessx working:

> To compile ChessX, you need Qt version 4.2.0 or above.

1. Compilation

Compiling the source is simple. Execute:
  qmake
and then
  make

If the compilation is successful you should be able to run ChessX
executable in bin subdirectory. It is called: chessx on Linux,
chessx.app on Mac OS, chessx.exe on Windows

1. Problems

If you have both Qt3 and Qt4 installed, verify that Qt4 is first
on your path. You may check it, running:
  qmake -v

But I don't know how to do the above exactly.

chessx I have downloaded and installed in `/usr/local/games` as that seems logical to me.How do I set the path to make qmake work?

Read "For simple projects, you only need to run qmake in the top level directory of your project."  So the directory above chessx or qt4?

NB: Since found out this is only to install locally where I was attempting to install remotely.

Comment: says it is installed but i cannot find it with which or qmake -v

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do. You seem to want to install the Qt libraries on a Red-Hat based system. Is that so? What is your actual question?

Comment: Yes I want to install qt on centos 6.4 in order to play chessx on my server

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and add that information. Include whatever it is that makes you think (not saying you're wrong, mind) that installing qt is the solution. Did you get an error message perhaps?

Comment: rpm -ql package-name will list

Comment: Please [EDIT] your question to add extra information, it is easy to miss and hard to read in the comments. Also remember to explain how you attempted to install chessx and how it failed (again, by editing your question).

Comment: @terdon don't mark me down and then not help- that's silly and very self involved in my opinion.

Comment: First of all I did not downvote you, despite wanting to, because your question already had two downvotes and I did not think that adding a third would help. Not only did I not downvote, I actually took the time to leave you 3 comments asking for information. You did not answer my questions, and you ignored both of my requests to edit yours. At some point while I was asleep, you finally did edit your question and since I did not magically notice and jump to your aid, you have the gall to accuse me of being "silly and self involved". Yeah, that really makes me want to help you out.

Comment: @cea - No one is obligated to help and it's perfectly OK to DV and not assist. It's usually best not to jump to conclusions either, but ask if whomever did the DV to please explain why so you can learn.

Comment: @cea - also the best way to interpret a DV is to take it as someone giving you feedback that your Q is either not clear or needs further refinements. Many of us try to help with this but it's likely that your Q is what needs your attention, not worrying about who did the DV'ing. I'll leave you with this too, I've read your Q multiple times and still don't really even know what you're trying to do, and I've used Fedora/RH for 20+ years. Try adding more of the actual details you've done thus far to your Q as others have asked for repeatedly.

Comment: Perhaps we speak different languages because honestly it makes perfect sense to me. I am often misunderstood on these forums but I can't really go out and have my brain tweaked to suit because it is what it is and I certainly do put in the effort to be understood.

Comment: Also I think people can request further information but I really honestly believe the marking down process just makes people feel frightened to get help- you start to lose confidence in yourself which is never a good thing in open source learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for [ChessX](http://chessx.sourceforge.net/node/3) appears to be a `.tgz` file, which is a compressed archive.  Move it to an empty directory and try `tar -xzf chessx-1-0-0.tgz`.  This will probably unpack into a directory of its own.  That is the top level directory from which you want to run `qmake`.

That will build the project, but it may not install it into a default location.  Have a look inside the directory and see if there is an INSTALL or README file.

> Do I need to `yum install qmake`?

If you get "command not found" for qmake, yes.  There may be other things you need to install; I don't know how friendly qmake is at explaining what those are to you.

Comment: NO OK I have chessX Already sorry - I am talking about compiling it. Anyway I am now trying the Qt tarball download and qmake doesn't work anywhere even in folders above the game folder.

Comment: Think I need serious lesson in directory paths and bash scripts!

Comment: Ah, you mean you need the Qt headers in order for chessX to compile -- these headers are used to compile programs that make use of Qt, but they are not included with the base Qt install because they aren't needed to *run* anything.  You don't have to compile Qt itself for that.  You need to install the `-devel` package (`yum install qt-devel`).

Comment: I made a mistake i am on Centos 6.5 ....oh this what I need to do! Ok let me try , I am just updating my system because keeps saying i don't have certain rpm package installed- I will remove and start with that after update and report back- thanks!

Comment: Still no luck. qmake not found.